# Flutter (Google) OrdinalComboBarLineChart inside MartialApp, error in release mode: NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

In a Flutter app I'm trying to implement the OrdinalComboBarLineChart found here: https://github.com/google/charts.

It works in debug mode. However, in release mode it throws an error, and it does not show the chart properly. I get the following error:

```
I/flutter (26577): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (26577):   ChartContainerRenderObject<String>#8d79e NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (26577):   parentData: <none>
I/flutter (26577):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=640.0)
I/flutter (26577):   semantic boundary
I/flutter (26577):   size: Size(0.0, 0.0)
I/flutter (26577): This RenderObject has no descendants.
```

I have located the problem to have something to do with the chart being inside a MaterialApp widget. Seeing as when I remove the MaterialApp widget, it does work.

Below is the code that produces this error:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(new OrdinalComboBarLineChart());
}

class OrdinalComboBarLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<charts.Series> seriesList = _createSampleData();

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
            height: 205.0,
            width: 350.0,
            child: charts.OrdinalComboChart(seriesList,
                animate: false,
                defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(areaOpacity: 0.8, includeArea: true),
                customSeriesRenderers: [
                  new charts.LineRendererConfig(customRendererId: 'LineOne'),
                ])));
  }

  /// Create series list with multiple series
  List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    var categoryOne = [
      new OrdinalSales('0:00', 0),
      new OrdinalSales('12:00', 0),
      new OrdinalSales('23:59', 25),
    ];

    var lineOne = [
      new OrdinalSales('0:00', 30),
      new OrdinalSales('12:00', 15),
      new OrdinalSales('23:59', 7),
    ];

    final Color myRed = const Color(0xFFEB4141);
    final Color myDarkBackground = const Color(0xFF101926);

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
          id: 'CategoryOne',
          colorFn: (_, __) => charts.Color(
              r: myRed.red, g: myRed.green, b: myRed.blue, a: myRed.alpha),
          domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
          measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
          data: categoryOne),
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
          id: 'LineOne ',
          colorFn: (_, __) => charts.Color(
              r: myDarkBackground.red,
              g: myDarkBackground.green,
              b: myDarkBackground.blue,
              a: myDarkBackground.alpha),
          domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
          measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
          data: lineOne)
        ..setAttribute(charts.rendererIdKey, 'LineOne'),
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;
  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

I am using
charts_flutter: ^0.5.0

Comment: So I just discovered that this happens in ^0.5.0, but not in ^0.4.0. Leaving this here as a reference to others who may face this issue.

Comment: FYI there's also a [github issue](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/177) about this (which it appears you've created so I'm sure you know about it =D), but the link will be useful to other people. Also, if downgrading works you should add that as an answer and accept it so this questions doesn't stay open. (and include the link to the issue there)